# How to do a grouped expanding

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

When you run `s.expanding().func` it will run func on the series increasing in size.
I have a series `s` where the index is a MultiIndex. The important level is dates. Many dates repeat.  I would like to run `expanding` so that instead of expanding by 1 row each iteration, it will expand by the entire next date.

The Hacky way of doing this is running expanding on a list sorted by date and then taking the last instance of each date, but I was wondering if there would be a cleaner way of doing this?

Edit:
The method that I listed above is SUPER slow since it calculates at every single location instead of once every so often, so I'm looking to find a way to make it faster and possibly stick with native Numpy or Pandas functions

Answer (score 0):

```
cur_dat = pd.DataFrame()
ret = {}
for key, new_dat in df.groupby(group_keys)
    cur_dat = cur_dat.append(new_dat)
    #DO STUFF
    ret[key] = return_Value
```

This also gives you a lot of control as to how you want to combine the data back.  Occasionally I unstack until its a series and append it all (Like `melt` in `R`).

Simple solution, only took reading all of the Pandas Source code in GroupBy and core.Windows to come up with it :)